# Implement interface from C# in F# and add method to update object property(return new instance)

Tags: c#, f#, immutability

I have the following interface defined in a C# library

```
public interface IMatch
{
    string CompetitionId { get; }
    int MatchNumber { get; }
    MatchType Type { get; }
    SeriesType SeriesType { get; }
    bool Finished { get; }
}
```

I've then created a type in my F# library that implements the interface like this

```
type Match(
            competitionId: string,
            finished: bool,
            matchNumber: int,
            seriesType: SeriesType,
            matchType: MatchType) = 
interface IMatch with
    member this.Finished with get() = finished
    member this.MatchNumber with get() = matchNumber
    member this.SeriesType with get() = seriesType
    member this.Type with get() = matchType
    member this.CompetitionId with get() = competitionId
```

Now, I read [this article](https://www.pluralsight.com/tech-blog/immutable-objects-in-csharp) and I saw the `WithUpdatedEmail`method on the Person type:

```
type Person = {
    FirstName: string
    LastName: string
    Email: string
}

with member this.WithUpdatedEmail email = { this with Email = email }
```

When calling that method, it will return a new Person instance with the updated email.
Is it possible to add a method like that on my `Match`type?
I've tried the following but I can't get it to compile(**The record label `Finished` is not defined**), Im completely new to F# so please bear with me if this isn't possible... :)

```
type Match(
            competitionId: string,
            finished: bool,
            matchNumber: int,
            seriesType: SeriesType,
            matchType: MatchType) = 
interface IMatch with
    member this.Finished with get() = finished
    member this.MatchNumber with get() = matchNumber
    member this.SeriesType with get() = seriesType
    member this.Type with get() = matchType
    member this.CompetitionId with get() = competitionId

with member this.Finished finished = { this with Finished = finished}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Copy and update record expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/copy-and-update-record-expressions) — the one, which allows you to write `{ rec with prop = val }` — is a convenient shortcut for creation of new record with a few changes from existing record instance.

I may be wrong, for sure, but this syntax is allowed for [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/records) types only, while you've declared a `Match` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/classes) with custom constructor, which is not a record.

So you may want to use a record instead.

```
type Match =
    { CompetitionId: string
      Finished: bool
      MatchNumber: int
      SeriesType: SeriesType
      MatchType: MatchType } 
    interface IMatch with
        member this.Finished with get() = this.Finished
        member this.MatchNumber with get() = this.MatchNumber
        member this.SeriesType with get() = this.SeriesType
        member this.Type with get() = this.MatchType
        member this.CompetitionId with get() = this.CompetitionId

    member this.WithFinished finished = { this with Finished = finished}
```

Member `WithFinished` is quite useless from F# point of view as you could always use `with` expression directly.

```
let m = { CompetitionID = "1"; Finished = false; ...}
let m2 = { m with CompetitionId = "42" }
```

But it may be suitable for C# interoperability.

If you want to leave `Match` as a class, then you should implement `WithFinished` manually providing all the arguments.

```
member this.WithFinished finished = 
    Match(competitionId, finished, matchNumber, seriesType, matchType)
```

But I doubt that it will be useful, because [interfaces](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/interfaces/) are always implemented as explicit in F#, it means you won't be able to access your `Match` class properties without a cast to `IMatch` from F# side.

Comment: Thank you! Yes im calling this code from C#, that's why I can't use the with expression directly.

Comment: @JOSEFtw added some strokes for implementation using classes, not records